# IndexOutOfBoundsException для пустой строки в конце файла

Tags: java

Есть такой код, читающий файл:

```
// Reading lines from a file.
String fileName = defineFileName(path.toString());
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Николай\\Documents\\TestSMS\\" + fileName));
String line1 = lines.get(0);
String line2 = lines.get(3);
String TextMessages = lines.get(13);
```

Если `lines.get(0)` - пустая строка, а `lines.get(13)` - не пустая, то `IndexOutOfBoundsException` не выбрасывает. Но если `lines.get(13)` - пустая строка в файле, то получаю:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13, Size: 13
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(ArrayList.java:665)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:477)
at com.app.sms.reader.impl.SimpleSmsReader.smsReader(SimpleSmsReader.java:103)
at com.app.sms.reader.impl.SimpleSmsReader.readSms(SimpleSmsReader.java:64)
at com.app.workflow.impl.SimpleSmsWorkflow.processSms(SimpleSmsWorkflow.java:32)
at com.app.starter.Main.main(Main.java:38)
```

Comment: lines.get(13) - попытка получить данные из коллекции по индексу которого нет, отсюда и исключение

Comment: Если lines.get(0); пустая строка а  TextMessages = lines.get(13); не пустая  IndexOutOfBoundsException не выбрасует.

Comment: Исправил, но это не решение  проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `Files.readAllLines` использует [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html): добавляет в свой список строки, полученные вызовом метода [readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) у reader-a, до тех пор, пока не получит в качестве строки `null`, что означает окончание потока данных. Звучит логично

Проблема в том, что метод `readLine` у `BufferedReader` возвращает `null` для последней строки, если у неё длина 0 (она пустая). По крайней мере, если судить по исходникам в JDK 1.8.0_131. Баг это или так и задумывалось, и менялось ли это в более новых версиях - не знаю

В итоге если нужно учитывать пустую строку в коде файла, то придётся читать файл более низкоуровневно

Comment: Ну 12 строка в файле тоже пустая и если к ней обращаться то все норм.

Comment: Если у вас заполнена только 13 строка, то на 12 у вас должен быть как минимум знак переноса, поэтому она не пустая. Пройдите отладчиком и посмотрите что он вам вернер в 12 строке.

Comment: @НиколайГнап ещё раз: речь про **последнюю** строку в файле. Если после 12-й строки у вас есть 13-я, то 12-я - это не последняя строка, и поэтому с ней всё норм